# what is quick and dirty extend/assign?

Tags: typescript

Could you please explain the meaning of below constructor? I have no idea what this defines...

```
export class Item {

  constructor(fields: any) {
    // Quick and dirty extend/assign fields to this model
    for (const f in fields) {
      // @ts-ignore
      this[f] = fields[f];
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's allowing the calling code to pass any object in as `fields` and then taking all of that object's enumerable properties (including inherited ones) and copying their values to the instance of `Item` that's being created. "Quick and dirty" is a common term for code that mostly works, but probably isn't best-practice. (That code certainly isn't best practice, in TypeScript; `Item` should define its shape [properties and methods] and only have properties that are defined for it.)